# Is it possible to remove a parted out set from BrickLink inventory?

Tags: bricklink

I have an inventory in BrickLink, in which I accidentally parted out (with the consolidation option) two sets instead of one.

Is there a way to remove the pieces of the second set somehow without manual part-by-part deletion?

Comment: Good question. It's not that obvious, it seems.

Comment: According to [this help article](https://www.bricklink.com/help.asp?helpID=197), you can, incredibly, part out a negative number of a set, which will result in the subtraction of that number of sets worth of parts from your inventory. I haven't been able to get this to work for my wanted list, though, and I'm not a seller (yet) so I can't verify if this works for sellers.

Comment: I can second LegoSonicBoy's comment. When I was a seller I wanted to remove the individual parts and add the set as an item. This can be done by parting out a negative set. Items can't have a quantity less than zero, so don't worry if you don't have all the parts in the inventory. I'd also suggest for LegoSonicBoy to post an answer :)

Answer (score 7):

Part out the same set, but with a negative quantity.

This does indeed work, as I have solved this very problem using this solution in the past:
[image: A double part-out is reversed]

This is a screenshot of my Part Out Log, and you can see I've accidentally parted out 10 sets twice. Then I've reversed the second part-out.

You can see a list of every set you've parted out (after mid-2009) and the quantity in [your Part Out Log](https://www.bricklink.com/inventoryInvLog.asp).

Answer (score -2):

I don't really think there is any way to do so other than to look at the inventory of the set and then do the manual part by part deletion, but if the parts from the parted out set consist of most or all the pieces in the cart then you could probably jot down the numbers of the parts not included in the set and delete everything in the cart. my answer could very well be incorrect or unusable, but this is the best I can do. Hope it helps.